# Java Lotto Number Generator LOOP

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, int

I just came up with this code that prints me only one line of 5 random lotto numbers and 1 random mega number.  I need to create a loop that asks the user "How many tickets would you like?", then prints the amount of lines that the user asks, instead of just one line.  How would I do this?  I believe its a for loop, but I'm not sure.

```
public static void main(String[] args)

    {

        int[] lottoNumber = new int[6];  
        {  
            lottoNumber[0] = (int) ((47 * Math.random()) + 1);  
            lottoNumber[1] = (int) ((47 * Math.random()) + 1);  
            lottoNumber[2] = (int) ((47 * Math.random()) + 1);  
            lottoNumber[3] = (int) ((47 * Math.random()) + 1);  
            lottoNumber[4] = (int) ((47 * Math.random()) + 1);  
            lottoNumber[5] = (int) ((27 * Math.random()) + 1);  
        }  

        System.out.println("Lottery Numbers: ");

        for(int i=0; i<1; i++)  
        {  
            System.out.print(lottoNumber[0] + " " );
            System.out.print(lottoNumber[1] + " " );
            System.out.print(lottoNumber[2] + " " );
            System.out.print(lottoNumber[3] + " " );
            System.out.print(lottoNumber[4] + " " );
            System.out.print("MEGA:(" + lottoNumber[5] + ")");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, using the scanner class you ask for the number of tickets.
Second, you need to make a method for the code generating the ticket.
Third, loop the getticket with printing.
and thats it. Here is the (working) code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.print("Enter number of tickets: ");
    Scanner numReader= new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = numReader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Lottery Numbers: ");
    System.out.println();
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)  
    {  
        int[] lottoNumber = getTicket();
        System.out.print(lottoNumber[0] + " " );
        System.out.print(lottoNumber[1] + " " );
        System.out.print(lottoNumber[2] + " " );
        System.out.print(lottoNumber[3] + " " );
        System.out.print(lottoNumber[4] + " " );
        System.out.print("MEGA:(" + lottoNumber[5] + ")");
        System.out.println();
    }  

}  
    public static int[] getTicket()
    {
        int[] lottoNumber = new int[6];
        {  
        lottoNumber[0] = (int) ((47 * Math.random()) + 1);  
        lottoNumber[1] = (int) ((47 * Math.random()) + 1);  
        lottoNumber[2] = (int) ((47 * Math.random()) + 1);  
        lottoNumber[3] = (int) ((47 * Math.random()) + 1);  
        lottoNumber[4] = (int) ((47 * Math.random()) + 1);  
        lottoNumber[5] = (int) ((27 * Math.random()) + 1);  
        }  
        return lottoNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Scanner to read the number of tickets wants to the user.(Scanner use to read value from the command line). Then create a for-loop and use number of tickets which is got from the user  as the condition value of the for-loop. Then add all above codes in to inside the for-loop.

Good Luck !!!